# Custom shape shape in React Native

Tags: react-native

```
<View
      style={{
        width: '100%',
        height: 10,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
        borderTopRightRadius: 10,
        backgroundColor: DefaultVariables.Colors.primary,
          }}
        />
```

make this shape

Can anybody help to make such kind of shape in React Native?

[image: img]

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you

```
     return (
    <View
      style={{
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        borderColor: '#000',
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        marginLeft: 60,
        marginTop: 100,
        borderTopRightRadius: 20,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
      }}>
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
          width: 200,
          height: 20,
          borderColor: '#000',
          borderWidth: 0.5,
          marginTop: 0,
          marginLeft: 0,
          borderTopRightRadius: 20,
          borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
        }}></View>
    </View>
  );
```